# Newtonian mechanics and calculus, looking for a good intro book to both together

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, calculus

I am looking for a book on Newtonian mechanics which is very careful to explain why, where and how you need to use calculus to develop physics. Or even, a book which introduce basic notion and propositions of calculus in terms of the latter being necessary to develop Newtonian mechanics.

My interest is partly pedagogical partly philosophical, and I would like to read something with all the subtle points well explained, and as self contained as possble.

Indeed, maybe I am looking to an essays on how to write such kind of book.

Comment: Your question is pretty general. If you explained problems you've had with existing book recommendations on the internet, perhaps we could help better. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-book-on-physics-and-calculus-for-beginners https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/35tc51/a_physics_book_for_a_beginner/

Comment: I am not looking for a book to study for SAT or JEE. My interest  is more of a pedagogical kind,  on how I could/should write such kind of a intro book. Do you know about [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Intuitive-Physical-Approach-Mathematics/dp/0486404536/ref=pd_sim_14_7?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=HB7DP0ZE9HMSZDATMVNR)? its  title is promising.

Answer (score -2):

Principia.  Anything else is just someone else's version.  How am I the first to suggest this?

D'alembert also wrote a decent primer.